# MySQL loop to inserting combine values

Tags: mysql, loops, combinations, insert-into

I have a little problem, I'd like to INSERT INTO myTable (id_product, id_tag) combined values

I know the method will be:

```
INSERT INTO myTable values (value1a, value1b),(value2a, value2b)
```

But problem is I have 934 products and 5 tags = 4670 combinations. So manually it will takes a ages to insert it! I know what id's has a products:

```
SELECT id_product FROM prodTable
```

So can anybody direct me what I should do (procedures, functions - I newer used it before, until today?)

Comment: _All_ 5 tags should go on _all_ products?

Comment: Yes peer-to-peer (each product with each tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a cartesian join:

```
insert into myTable
select id_product, id_tag
from products, tags
```

SELECT will select all products id, combined with all tags id, and rows will be inserted in myTable.

Comment: Thanks **@fthiella** and **@Joachim Isaksson** you both help me out very quickly.

Final code:

    INSERT INTO `myTable`
 SELECT p.id_product, t.id_tag FROM `prodTable` p, `tagTable` t
  WHERE t.id_tag >=64
I did not expect that it can be so easily solved. It will beuseful for the future for me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use either CURSORS or LOOPs. And combine them.

One example of each one:

-LOOP

```
DECLARE y INT DEFAULT 2010;

cur_year_loop : LOOP
    IF y=2013 THEN
        LEAVE cur_year_loop;
    END IF;

    ...do things...

    SET y=y+1;
END LOOP cur_year_loop;
```

-CURSOR

```
DECLARE cur_percentages CURSOR FOR SELECT value FROM test_percentages;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done_perc = TRUE;
OPEN cur_percentages;
cur_percentages_loop : LOOP
    IF done_perc THEN
        CLOSE cur_percentages;
        LEAVE cur_percentages_loop;
    END IF;

    ...do things...
END LOOP cur_percentages_loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

If all tags should go on all products, it's fairly simple (where 1 to 5 are the five tag_ids)

```
INSERT INTO myTable (id_product, id_tag) SELECT id_product, 1 FROM prodTable;
INSERT INTO myTable (id_product, id_tag) SELECT id_product, 2 FROM prodTable;
INSERT INTO myTable (id_product, id_tag) SELECT id_product, 3 FROM prodTable;
INSERT INTO myTable (id_product, id_tag) SELECT id_product, 4 FROM prodTable;
INSERT INTO myTable (id_product, id_tag) SELECT id_product, 5 FROM prodTable;
```

You could do it in one insert and a union, but this ways is probably the most clear.

[A simple SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edbe8/1).

Of course, if you have the tags in a table, @fthiella's answer is even simpler.